# Can I get a variable number of generic types for Java classes, or even in general?

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, tuples, variadic

I would like to forge a generic data class by the name of "EnumTuple" that stores a natural number of different Enum elements from different Enum classes together in one Tuple.
Say I got those three Enum classes:

```
public Enum Gender {
    FEMALE, MALE, OTHER
}

public enum Age {
    YOUNG, MIDDLEAGED, OLD
}

public enum Personality {
    EXTROVERT, INTROVERT
}
```

I would like to be able to instantiate the EnumTuple class like so:

```
EnumTuple person1 = new EnumTuple<Gender, Age, Personality>(Gender.OTHER, Age.MIDDLEAGED, Personality.EXTROVERT);
EnumTuple person2 = new EnumTuple<Personality, Gender>(Personality.INTROVERT, Gender.FEMALE);
EnumTuple person3 = new EnumTuple<Age>(Age.OLD);
```

But I have no idea how to get there or if it is even possible to write such a data class in Java or Kotlin to begin with because it looks like each class can only have a fixed number of generic types.

For those curious, I'm trying to implement a clean and general version of the Candidate Elimination Algorithm (https://artint.info/html/ArtInt_193.html), in which the set of input features is that tuple of enum elements I am trying to design.

And lastly, if you have got a workaround for me on hand or know another programming language that supports a variable number of generic types, please let me know

Comment: How would you use `EnumTuple`? What method you expected to provide?

Comment: @samabcde I intend to compare two EnumTuples of similar generic types on an element-by-element basis to determine if they are equal, and in which elements they differ.
Let's set up some example variables:

```EnumTuple<Gender, Age> person1 = EnumTuple<Gender, Age>(Gender.FEMALE, Age.YOUNG);
EnumTuple<Gender, Age> person2 = EnumTuple<Gender, Age>(Gender.MALE, Age.YOUNG);```

Now I'd like to be able to compare them:
```assertFalse(person1.isEqualTo(person2));
assertEquals(person1.getDifferenceTo(person2), [false, true]);```

Comment: I know this can also be achieved by a normal generic class having a fixed amount of generic types. I just wanted to make my implementation even more general and reusable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it neither in Java or Kotlin since, as you imagined, each class can only have a fixed number of generic types.

The only workaround you can do here, without specifying all the combinations manually beforehand, it's to check the instance of the enums every time you use them creating a `EnumTuple` with `vararg Enum<*>`.

**e.g.** (in Kotlin)

```kotlin
class EnumTuple(vararg enums: Enum<*>)
```

> [...] or know another programming language that supports a variable number of generic types, please let me know.

This feature is supported in C++ using variadic templates.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

Answer (score 0):

Base on the use cases, `EnumTuple` will be compared using each feature it has. And the number of feature is flexible, I would suggest the following design.

1. Add a enum `FeatureType`, which will contains all possible features.
2. Add a interface `Feature`, and each feature enum will implement this interface.
3. In `EnumTuple`, we will use a `Map<FeatureType, Feature>` to store the features.

---

```
public enum FeatureType {
    AGE, GENDER, PERSONALITY;
}

public enum Age implements Feature {
    YOUNG, MIDDLEAGED, OLD;

    @Override
    public FeatureType getFeatureType() {
        return FeatureType.AGE;
    }
}

public enum Personality implements Feature {
    EXTROVERT, INTROVERT;

    @Override
    public FeatureType getFeatureType() {
        return FeatureType.PERSONALITY;
    }
}

public enum Gender implements Feature {
    FEMALE, MALE, OTHER;

    @Override
    public FeatureType getFeatureType() {
        return FeatureType.GENDER;
    }
}

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Assert;

public class EnumTuple {
    private Map<FeatureType, Feature> featureTypeToFeatureMap = new HashMap<>();

    public EnumTuple(List<Feature> features) {
        for (Feature feature : features) {
            featureTypeToFeatureMap.put(feature.getFeatureType(), feature);
        }
    }

    public boolean hasFeature(FeatureType featureType) {
        return featureTypeToFeatureMap.containsKey(featureType);
    }

    public Feature getFeature(FeatureType featureType) {
        return featureTypeToFeatureMap.get(featureType);
    }

    public Map<FeatureType, Boolean> getDifferenceTo(EnumTuple enumTuple) {
        if (!this.featureTypeToFeatureMap.keySet().equals(enumTuple.featureTypeToFeatureMap.keySet())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Contains different featureTypes");
        }
        Map<FeatureType, Boolean> difference = new HashMap<>();
        for (FeatureType featureType : this.featureTypeToFeatureMap.keySet()) {
            difference.put(featureType, this.getFeature(featureType).equals(enumTuple.getFeature(featureType)));
        }
        return difference;
    }

    public boolean isEqualsTo(EnumTuple other) {
        if (featureTypeToFeatureMap == null) {
            if (other.featureTypeToFeatureMap != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!featureTypeToFeatureMap.equals(other.featureTypeToFeatureMap))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EnumTuple person1 = new EnumTuple(Arrays.asList(Gender.OTHER, Age.MIDDLEAGED, Personality.EXTROVERT));
        EnumTuple person2 = new EnumTuple(Arrays.asList(Gender.OTHER, Age.MIDDLEAGED, Personality.EXTROVERT));
        EnumTuple person3 = new EnumTuple(Arrays.asList(Gender.FEMALE, Age.MIDDLEAGED, Personality.EXTROVERT));
        Assert.assertTrue(person1.isEqualsTo(person2));
        Assert.assertFalse(person1.isEqualsTo(person3));
        Assert.assertEquals(person1.getDifferenceTo(person2).toString(), "{PERSONALITY=true, GENDER=true, AGE=true}");
        Assert.assertEquals(person1.getDifferenceTo(person3).toString(), "{PERSONALITY=true, GENDER=false, AGE=true}");
    }
}
```